# React, button with link and onClick

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```
      <ButtonSendMoney
        handleSendMoney={handleSendMoney}
        link={link}
      />
```

This one renders this:

```
  <Link to={link}>
    <button
      onClick={handleSendMoney}
    >
     Go
    </button>
  </Link>
```

So, my problem is my `handleSendMoney`  handler is setting the `link`, in other words:

When I click the button, some actions are triggered, that modifies the value of `link` but with that code, it will navigate to the `link` value before be modified. So how could I "await" and wait for the handler be finished and then pass the proper link props to the component?

Edit:

I could edit the  component, remove that  and just redirect inside the handler mentioned above, but how?

Comment: How is `link` being modified? Is it in the parent's state?

Comment: yes, it's a local state modified in a useEffect that has a dependencie from redux, so the mentioned handler triggers an action that update that redux value, then link is locally set

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that render a button inside a Link is a good idea, since you are triggering two dependent events.

In case you are using react-router-dom, you should do some think like this in your handleSendMoney function:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default Exemple(){

  const history = useHistory()
  handleSendMoney(){
      //modifies the value of link
      history.push(link)
  }

  return(
      <ButtonSendMoney
        handleSendMoney={handleSendMoney}
        link={link}
      />
  );

}
```

And your ButtonSendMoney should be like:

```
 <button onClick={handleSendMoney}>
   Go
 </button>
```